# WSO2Emm - Unable to register android device

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

I couldn't register my android device to emm.

I get following error:

> Authentication Failed: Cannot proceed the authentication. Please
>   contact administrator.

I have created user in managment consol using admin, the credential is tested , I could connect to https://localhost:9443/emm/ with it.

Also I disable my firewall, but I couldn't register the device.

PS: I working in a developer environment, I have installed server as a windows service , and android agent to my galaxy note 10.

**Edit1:**

Here is the [logcat](https://ceit.aut.ac.ir/~9031020/LogCat_enrollment.txt):

```
07-12 23:21:03.454: D/ServerUtils(20186): Attempt #1 to register
07-12 23:21:03.454: E/(20186): in
07-12 23:21:03.459: I/SurfaceFlinger(2276): id=176 createSurf (1x1),1 flag=4, Buthenticat
07-12 23:21:03.459: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(2988): sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
07-12 23:21:03.459: I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(2988): visibility is same
07-12 23:21:03.469: W/System.err(20186): java.io.IOException: KeyStore integrity check failed.
07-12 23:21:03.469: W/System.err(20186):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.bc.BcKeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(BcKeyStoreSpi.java:862)
07-12 23:21:03.469: W/System.err(20186):    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:589)
07-12 23:21:03.469: W/System.err(20186):    at org.wso2.emm.agent.utils.HTTPConnectorUtils.getCertifiedHttpClient(HTTPConnectorUtils.java:56)
07-12 23:21:03.469: W/System.err(20186):    at org.wso2.emm.agent.utils.HTTPConnectorUtils.postData(HTTPConnectorUtils.java:238)
07-12 23:21:03.469: W/System.err(20186):    at org.wso2.emm.agent.utils.HTTPConnectorUtils.sendWithTimeWait(HTTPConnectorUtils.java:107)
07-12 23:21:03.469: W/System.err(20186):    at org.wso2.emm.agent.utils.HTTPConnectorUtils.getClientKey(HTTPConnectorUtils.java:89)
07-12 23:21:03.469: W/System.err(20186):    at org.wso2.emm.agent.AuthenticationActivity$12.doInBackground(AuthenticationActivity.java:444)
07-12 23:21:03.474: W/System.err(20186):    at org.wso2.emm.agent.AuthenticationActivity$12.doInBackground(AuthenticationActivity.java:1)
07-12 23:21:03.474: W/System.err(20186):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-12 23:21:03.474: W/System.err(20186):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-12 23:21:03.474: W/System.err(20186):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-12 23:21:03.474: W/System.err(20186):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-12 23:21:03.474: W/System.err(20186):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-12 23:21:03.474: W/System.err(20186):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-12 23:21:03.474: E/display(2276): invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
07-12 23:21:03.474: V/ServerUtils(20186): 192.168.1.157Posting '{password=123456, username=9031020}' to https://192.168.1.157:9443/emm/api/devices/clientkey
07-12 23:21:03.474: V/ServerUtils(20186): Posting 'password=123456&username=9031020' to https://192.168.1.157:9443/emm/api/devices/clientkey
07-12 23:21:03.474: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(2988): sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
07-12 23:21:03.474: I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(2988): visibility is same
07-12 23:21:03.474: E/ServerUtils(20186): Failed to register on attempt 1
07-12 23:21:03.474: E/ServerUtils(20186): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 23:21:03.474: E/ServerUtils(20186):   at org.wso2.emm.agent.utils.HTTPConnectorUtils.postData(HTTPConnectorUtils.java:279)
07-12 23:21:03.474: E/ServerUtils(20186):   at org.wso2.emm.agent.utils.HTTPConnectorUtils.sendWithTimeWait(HTTPConnectorUtils.java:107)
07-12 23:21:03.474: E/ServerUtils(20186):   at org.wso2.emm.agent.utils.HTTPConnectorUtils.getClientKey(HTTPConnectorUtils.java:89)
07-12 23:21:03.474: E/ServerUtils(20186):   at org.wso2.emm.agent.AuthenticationActivity$12.doInBackground(AuthenticationActivity.java:444)
07-12 23:21:03.474: E/ServerUtils(20186):   at org.wso2.emm.agent.AuthenticationActivity$12.doInBackground(AuthenticationActivity.java:1)
07-12 23:21:03.474: E/ServerUtils(20186):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-12 23:21:03.474: E/ServerUtils(20186):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-12 23:21:03.474: E/ServerUtils(20186):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-12 23:21:03.474: E/ServerUtils(20186):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-12 23:21:03.474: E/ServerUtils(20186):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-12 23:21:03.474: E/ServerUtils(20186):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-12 23:21:03.479: D/mali_winsys(20186): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
07-12 23:21:03.484: D/ProgressBar(20186): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
07-12 23:21:03.484: D/ProgressBar(20186): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
07-12 23:21:03.484: D/ProgressBar(20186): updateDrawableBounds: right = 96
07-12 23:21:03.484: D/ProgressBar(20186): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 96
07-12 23:21:03.484: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(2773): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
07-12 23:21:03.484: D/EnterpriseDeviceManager(2773): ContainerId: 0
07-12 23:21:03.484: W/LicenseLogService(2773): log() failed
07-12 23:21:03.489: E/ViewRootImpl(20186): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
07-12 23:21:03.489: E/display(2276): invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
07-12 23:21:03.489: W/InputMethodManagerService(2773): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43129a78 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@438c5008
```

**Edit2:**

The above error was because of mistake in making self-signed certificate, now I couldn't register the device. here is the [image](https://ceit.aut.ac.ir/~9031020/login_error.jpg)!

and below is the logcat:

```
07-15 01:56:38.857: V/ServerUtils(28027): 192.168.1.157Posting '{password=123456, username=9031020}' to https://192.168.1.157:9443/emm/api/devices/clientkey
07-15 01:56:38.857: V/ServerUtils(28027): Posting 'password=123456&username=9031020' to https://192.168.1.157:9443/emm/api/devices/clientkey
07-15 01:56:38.857: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(2770): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
07-15 01:56:38.857: D/EnterpriseDeviceManager(2770): ContainerId: 0
```

Comment: What is the logcat output of the Android Device, while you get the error message? Would you please post it?

Comment: @flock.dux Here is the [logcat](https://ceit.aut.ac.ir/~9031020/LogCat_enrollment.txt)

Comment: It seems that, the device can not complete the request to the https://192.168.1.157:9443/emm/api/devices/clientkey with the username and password provided. Is there a firewall or something that may block the connection. Would you please try to access the link via the Android device's browser

Comment: @flock.dux I turn off my firewall and try to connect via android device's browser, here is the [result](https://ceit.aut.ac.ir/~9031020/web_check.jpg)!

Comment: Did you create the user via the EMM's User page? Also do you specify any domain, please live the domain field empty at the agent's activation. And try with a  username with letters not only numbers.

Comment: yes, here is the [User](https://ceit.aut.ac.ir/~9031020/user.jpg) page. also I leave the domain field empty.

Comment: Also I create new user with zahra72 username, but I get same error.

Comment: What is the server log while you are trying to register? Would you post it?

Comment: As I am new to this, could you please say how can I check server log?

Comment: Maybe the way I create self signed certificate is wrong, here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/113vqQdA7dzVgnNfZFgqko-UG4_LfKySQs5_ml-jEdXk/edit?usp=sharing), could you please check it for me?

Comment: I guess that is the problem because, in the logcat it says that KeyStore integrity check failed.

Comment: I go through step in documentation, which step I do wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83224/discussion-between-user3933607-and-flock-dux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.

I install the server again and go through steps [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/Registering+a+Device). 
The problem was login to management consol before EMM consols.